# Run Symfony command on server

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I now have my application on **Symfony 1.4** on the server. I use **FileZilla** to upload files, but how can I now use the command line, for example, `plugin:publish-assets`?

Is this possible with FileZilla?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Do you want to upload your code to your production server? If this is the case, you might want to consider some type of [revision control/versioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) system.

Comment: i uploaded my code, but i must use Symfony command, for example plugin:publish-assets or symfony clear:cache

Comment: You're going to have to access the CLI of your production server, either through SSH or some other means. Contact your host for more information on how to do that.

Comment: Workarounds: cc is simply deleting the contents of the cache folder, publish-assets simply copies (or symlinks) the contents of the plugins' web directories under the web directory (you can copy your local web to the server's web to achieve the same effect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work with symfony's CLI in production, you need SSH access to the server the application is hosted on. You cannot run shell commands *(like `symfony`)* through FileZille; FileZilla is FTP software and nothing more.

Many shared hosting providers do not provide SSH access because of the inherent security risks involved. You need to find out if your host provides SSH access, get it enabled if it's not, or move to a new host if having shell access is crucial.

CLI access for a symfony makes a lot of common tasks easier to manage in production, but what you're asking *(deploying assets to the web directory)* can be done with only FTP access.

**[There is a whole chapter written on deploying a Symfony 1.4 application](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/22)**

In your case, just run `php symfony plugin:publish-assets` locally, **then** push your code via FTP.

I'd strongly recommend looking into a hosting environment that does offer SSH access though. Combining symfony with a VCS like [git](http://git-scm.com/) and setting up your server to pull tags directly from your repository, to simply using symfony's `project:deploy` CLI task for deployment makes managing the code in production oh-so-much easier.